# What's the Meaning of "/ 1024 / 1024, 2" in the next SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I was looking for a way to know the sizes of my databases so I ended up using this query.

````
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Tamaño (MB)"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema;```
````

Comment: It's used to display the total number of bytes into megabytes. 1 MB = 1024 × 1024 bytes (well, technically this would be Mebibytes)

Comment: Check the table of Byte calculation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: Probably a big clue is the `(MB)` in the column alias.

Answer (score 1):

The `data_length` and `index_length` are probably bytes.

---

The `/ 1024 / 1024` is `divide by 1024 then divide by 1024`.

Bytes divided by `1024` gives you kilobytes.

Kilobytes divided by `1024` gives you megabytes.

Thus the result is **the number of megabytes** what is also suggested by the label `Tamaño (MB)` (even though I don't speak this language, but the `MB` is obvious).

`, 2` is the second parameter to `ROUND`, giving the number of decimal places to round to.